# Iphone View Rotation not functioning properly

Tags: iphone, ios, view, mkmapview, autorotate

I have a simple 1 screen app, with 1 View.. the view contains

a button, an textbox and a button across the top

A segmented controller across the bottom

and a MapView in between.

In portrait mode all is right with the world.. So I decided to begin to allow Orientation change...

in IB all views and elements and even the root window have autoResizeSubviews set

in My AppDelegate and my viewController I have also programatically added SetAutoResizeSubviews to yes explicitely  I have set the autoResizingMask in the Root Window and the View Controller to FlexibleWidht | Flexibile Height

I have added the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation in my ViewController to always return true.

Yet, it doesn't work.. Or should I say it doesn't rotate properly.. in both portrait modes everything looks great, but both landscape modes, things don't get laid out or resized properly.. Basically all I see is the mapview, and its size gets slightly wider, but not much than the portrait mode, and it doesn't fill up the screen top to bottom.. all other interface elements with the exception of one button are invisible and it appears on TOP of the mapview.. as thought it just happened to be layed out over the view by coincidence than any design.

Anyone have any ideas what I am missing, or why?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like the mapview is getting its height resized properly, but its width is not, and then its not being layed out where it should be but is being put right at the top left of the window.  I am wondering if it is doing this with all the elements, so they are all just overlaying each other at the top left of the screen with the mapview covering up all the other elements besides the one button that is visible that was likely added after the mapview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say "I have set the autoResizingMask in the Root Window and the View Controller" but that is a red herring. It is the buttons, the text box, the segmented controller, and the map view that have to have the correct `autoresizingMask`. If this view is being designed in the nib, you can set the values there and then turn the orientation right there in the nib and see what happens.

If you are unable to work out good `autoresizingMask` values for all those interface elements, implement `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` and perform the layout alterations in code when called upon to do so.

Comment: Yes, I figured this out... Was just about to post it.. I didn't have the view AutoSizing set properly in IB so everything was indeed getting locked to the top right of the window on landscape... I am still having some issues with things not resizing quite the way I would like but at least the page appears with everything in its proper place thank you.

Comment: Now to play with those autoresize lines in IB until it does what I want.

Comment: Matt,  the textfield and segmented controller do not allow adjustable height, at least that I can tell in IB.. so since these elements don't resize in the vertical space... how to I make sure the mapview in between respects their boundaries?  IE don't let the mapview's bounds go into the fixed size of the segmented controller and edit text field even if the scaling calcluations would put them there?